# How to have url's like domain.com/<article-name> in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have a articles controller and a view function in it to show an individual article, so my url's are like

`http://domain.com/articles/view/<article-id>/<article-title>`

My code:

```
class Articles extends CI_Controller {  
   function view($id=NULL,$slug=""){
        //Code to fetch article details from DB by id
    }
}
```

How do it make my url's to look like `http://domain.com/<article-title>`

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define all the controllers in routes config addressing to their own methods. At the end of routes config add following rule --

```
$route['(:any)']   = 'articles/view/$1';
```

All the requests other than previously defined route will now be served by `artcile/view` controller method.

Next part is create a mapping table that will map article titles to article ids. You can get article title with

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

in `view` function.

Whenever article is updated with title, then update mapping table as well.

Comment: @varun1505 you could use the article title as the unique id and pass it as the first segment in the URI

Answer (score 1):

I did the similar thing for my blog.
@Varun As per Sachin's comment this is underline routing path **domain.com/articles/view/** actually you will see url as **domain.com/** as expected.

Also I have extended for Level Urls like this

```
$route['spring/(:any)'] = "controller_name/method_name/$1";
$route['hibernate/(:any)'] = "controller_name/method_name/$1";
```

So actual URL look like this

```
domainname.com/spring/spring-jdbc-example which is mapped to  "controller_name/method_name/$1"
```